# Auto suggestion not showing worldwide results - the reslts are limited. How to I get all cities/states worldwide?

Tags: here-api

I’m here because I’m clueless and need help. Currently using Google Places API and moving away because the price has become crazy. Averaging about 300,000 queries a month with Google Places.

I own a dating website where people can search by location. Currently with Google Places API, I can begin typing a location in the search box and Google will auto suggest locations.

I only allow people to search starting with “city”, state, town, zip, postal codes, country.
(I don’t allow people to search street names or addresses).

After I select the location from the autocomplete drop down it shows me matches within a 100 mile radius.

The important thing is that the search box show suggestions throughout the world as I’m typing in a location. (not limited to one country). I need the auto suggestions to be detailed and cover all cities in all countries. (or as many cities/towns as here.com’s database has). So worldwide suggestions on the autocomplete..

I just want to replace Google with Here so that it does the same thing with the drop down autocomplete.

Can anyone give me suggestions on how to make this work? I don’t need exact step by step instructions. More along the lines of just telling me what I should be using to get these results. (but if you are feeling generous, the more detailed you can be, the better).

I don’t know if this is allowed or not, but I’d be willing to pay for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer robust autocompletion API by HERE. The detailed documentation, which includes API reference, examples can be found at the following link :

developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoding_suggestions

Geocoding and Search category includes couple of APIs that enable you to come up with your business solution in more efficient ways. please refer

developer.here.com/products/geocoding-and-search

Happy Coding..!